# Linear Regression vs. Moving Average

Tags: regression, forecasting, moving-average

I'm trying to build a model that predicts a player future performance, but on a daily basis. So far I have a weighted moving average for the last three years worth of data. Something I'm interested in doing is preparing a section that gives a player a boost based. It would be a positive boost if they haven't met their expectation in the last "x" amount of games (reasoning being is because some players who are good aren't going to commonly go several games without a goal/point) and a negative boost if they have come close to their expectation in the last "x" amount of games.

Would I be best using weighted moving average in this situation or linear regression? My formula I was thinking about was this:

(game 1 results - game 1 expectation) + (game 2 results - game 2 expectation) + (game 3 results - game 3 expectation)* (boost factor)

Is this a smart approach or would it likely fail? If the latter, is there a better process to use to complete this task?